# Receiving email via SMTP

Tags: java, email, smtp

Is it possible to receive email via SMTP protocol? My client insist it is workable and refuse to provide pop3/imap.

If yes, what java api/library should I use?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

How about this one?

> [SubEtha SMTP](https://code.google.com/p/subethasmtp/) is a Java library which allows your application to receive SMTP mail with a simple, easy-to-understand API.

Comment: great, i will look into that.